# How do I know whether an expression is a continuation?

Tags: racket, continuations

```
(+ 2 (let/cc cont
    (begin
     (set! global-cont cont)
     3)))
5

global-cont
#<continuation>

(global-cont 5) ; global-cont: (+ 2 _)
7
```

I know the whole block `(+ 2 ... 3)))` is a continuation. But why `global-cont` is a continuation also? I tried to check the `let/cc` [document](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-current-continuation%29%29), but it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this expression:

```
(let/cc cont body ...)
```

`cont` is a *continuation* `(+ 2 _)`, and in the body you're doing this:

```
(set! global-cont cont)
```

So basically you're assigning `cont` to `global-cont`, making it also a continuation.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would disagree that "the whole block (+ 2 ...) is a continuation". If by "continuation" you mean "a value captured by let/cc or its equivalent (call/cc etc.)," then the whole block is not a continuation.

So: `cont` is a continuation because you captured it with `let/cc`. `global-cont` is a continuation because you assigned a continuation to it.